# Does a delegate assignment create a new copy in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, mono, garbage-collection

I read an article about C# and performance considerations ([here](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RobertZubek/20150504/242572/C_memory_and_performance_tips_for_Unity.php#comment267172))

In the article, it is said that a delegate assignment triggers memory allocations, e.g:

> every single local variable assignment like "Func fn = Fn"
>   creates a new instance of the delegate class Func on the heap

I wanted to know if that is true, and if it is - how is that implemented? i am not familiar with any way that a reference assignment can trigger extra memory allocation in C#.

Answer (score 5):

The article is right. Quite easy to test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string[]> main = Main;
    Action<string[]> main2 = Main;
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(main, main2)); // False
}
```

http://ideone.com/dgNxPn

If you look at the IL code generated http://goo.gl/S47Wfy, it is quite clear what happens:

```
    IL_0002: ldftn void Test::Main(string[])
    IL_0008: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<string[]>::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_000d: stloc.0
    IL_000e: ldnull

    IL_000f: ldftn void Test::Main(string[])
    IL_0015: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<string[]>::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_001a: stloc.1
```

So there are **two** `newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`1::.ctor(object, native int)`

Note that you are right that this is counterintuitive:

```
public class TestEvent
{
    public event Action Event;

    public TestEvent()
    {
        Action d1 = Print;
        Action d2 = Print;

        // The delegates are distinct
        Console.WriteLine("d1 and d2 are the same: {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(d1, d2));

        Event += d1;
        Event -= d2;

        // But the second one is able to remove the first one :-)
        // (an event when is empty is null)
        Console.WriteLine("d2 was enough to remove d1: {0}", Event == null);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestEvent");
    }
}
```

With `event`s for example, you can use an "equivalent but not the same" delegate to remove another delegate, as shown in the example. See https://ideone.com/xeJ6LO

Comment: So how is that implemented? is it something that the runtime supports? classes that i declare obviously don't behave this way.

Comment: @lysergic-acid Classes that you declare behave the same way. If you explicitly call `new C()` twice, you get two instances of `C`. If you define an implicit conversion operator that calls `new C()`, and implicitly perform that conversion twice, you also get two instances of `C`.

Comment: @hvd i guess the issue in this code is that you don't explicitly call new C() twice. So it's some kind of sugar being added by the compiler that calls new twice, hence 2 different instances.

Comment: @lysergic-acid https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx In C# 1.0 and 1.2 you had to explicitly do a `new MyDelegate(function)`. Then in C# 2.0 they made it implicit. I'll add that even that form was a fake, because the signature of the constructor of a delegate is `MyDelegate(object, IntPtr)`, where `object` is the reference to the "target" object of the delegate (the `this` that will be used by the delegated method) and the `IntPtr` is the address of the method. You can see it if you watch how the `newobj` is called in IL code (see the second block of code)

Comment: @lysergic-acid That's why I already mentioned implicit conversions in my comment. If you use implicit conversions with your own classes, the calling code can get `int i = 1; C c1 = i; C c2 = i;` (without any explicit `new C()`s), yet get `!object.ReferenceEquals(c1, c2)` too. In fact, it happens even with implicit conversions to built-in types: `int i = 1; object o1 = i; object o2 = i;` Now what does `object.ReferenceEquals(o1, o2)` report?

Comment: Yes but in this particular case i don't think that it is an implicit conversion (an implicit operator), thats what confused me.

Comment: @lysergic-acid It would have been more complex and slow to do the opposite, and it wouldn't have been very optimal: the CLR must have maintained a "Dictionary/Cache" of "active" delegates, and matched the delegate you want to one of those already present. If matched then return it, otherwise create a new delegate and add it to this Dictionary/Cache. This is done for example for `typeof(xxx)`, but in this case it has a motivation: a Type as a lifetime equal to the lifetime of the program, and comparing types is quite common. A delegate normally has a shorter lifetime, and you don't compare them

Comment: @lysergic-acid But you are right that it is counterintuitive, if you think how you use `add` and `remove` (`+=` and `-=`) with `event`s, as shown in the example I've added.

Comment: @xanatos: An alternative would have been to have the compiler add a hidden field to an object for each method that will have a delegate created for it, and then have the code which would implicitly convert a method group to a delegate fetch the appropriate field.  This would be bad for short-lived delegates, but could be helpful in some scenarios involving longer-lived ones.

Comment: @supercat The compiler can't know which methods will be "delegated". Potentially all the methods can be delegated (through reflection for example). And you can create a delegate to an already compiled method in another assembly. Then there is the problem that there is not one single type of delegate for each signature: `void delegate One()` and `void delegate Two()` are distinct delegates for the same signature

Comment: @xanatos: A compiler could identify places where a class creates multiple delegates to one of its own method and cache one within the class itself, though without knowing how often various methods are called it's hard to know when such an "optimization" is really helpful.  The main place delegate equivalence is used in .NET is in the event pattern, and some other patterns might be better [e.g. use event subscription objects which are disposable (similar to `IObserver`) and also suppose a "still interested?" query (each subscription request should ask two current subscribers if they're still...

Comment: interested, thus ensuring that event leaks don't cause subscription lists to grow without bound)].  Having to construct a new delegate object just for the purpose of finding one which is equivalent and unsubscribing it is a bit ugly, but the pattern is nonetheless pretty popular.

Comment: @supercat But in the end, it is rare that one uses the `remove` of the event, it is rare to have an event with more that one or two listeners, rare * rare == very rare.

Comment: @xanatos: Properly written code should remove events; there are a lot of cases where code can get by without it, but code that subscribes to an event from a public object and never unsubscribes creates dependencies upon the reference usage patterns elsewhere in the code to avoid memory leaks.  Of course, that ties in with another peeve of mine--C# should have had the use of method-invocation syntax on an event do an "invoke-if-non-null" sequence.  How many hundreds of thousands of lines of code would that one feature have saved by now?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you're declaring a new instance of the delegate and initializing it as such:

```
Func fn=new Func(Fn);  // hidden by syntactic sugar
```

However the article is misleading in regards to the higher memory usage, it's the same as the others, it just never got garbage collected because it's such a measly amount of it.

Comment: I thought it was just creating another reference to the same delegate

Comment: Of what delegate? `Fn` is a function.