# Preventing a class member from cloning a delegate reference on assignment?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, ref

I'm trying to use a class to simplify dynamically binding and unbinding a method callback to a delegate. When the Bound property is changed to a different value, the callback is added or removed from the actionEvent delegate depending on whether bound is true or false.

```
public class Binding
{
    private bool bound;

    private Action actionEvent;
    private Action callback;

    //Constructor
    public Binding(ref Action actionEvent, Action callback, bool isBound = true)
    {
        this.actionEvent = actionEvent; //actionEvent is either being cloned here, or whenever it's referenced
        this.callback = callback;
        this.bound = isBound;

        if (this.bound)
        {
            Debug.Log("Binding callback to event!");
            this.actionEvent += this.callback;  //This is a reference to the plrInput class
        }
    }

    //Bound property binds and unbinds the callback function to the event when changed
    public bool Bound
    {
        get { return bound; }
        set 
        {
            if (bound != value)
            {
                bound = value;
                if (bound)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Rebinding callback!");
                    actionEvent += callback;
                    return;
                }
                actionEvent -= callback;
                Debug.Log("Unbinding callback!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class is instantiated in the start method like so:

```
void Start
{
     Binding JumpBinding = new Binding(ref plrInput.OnSpacePressed, Jump); 
     // plrInput.OnSpacePressed is a delegate from another class which is invoked when I press space
     // Jump is a method which causes the player to jump
}
```

I'm new to c# and I learned about delegates and the ref keyword yesterday, so maybe my problem stems from a misunderstanding. The problem I'm running into is that the class member actionEvent in Binding is just a clone of the actionEvent argument passed through the constructor, even though I pass it by reference. I was able to confirm this through testing.

When I invoke plrInput.OnSpacePressed while the callback is bound to the Binding class member actionEvent, the callback is not being called. Does anyone have an explanation for why I'm getting this behavior, and how I can potentially fix this problem or if there's a better approach?

Comment: `I was able to confirm this through testing` How? What made you think it's a copy?

Comment: I added a debug method which prints "Space Pressed" to the OnSpacePressed delegate from inside the plrInput class. When I manually invoke the actionEvent argument from the Binding class' constructor, the debug method is called. When I instead invoke the actionEvent member of the Binding class after it's assigned, nothing happens. To me this indicates that the plrInput.OnSpacePressed delegate is being duplicated either when it's assigned to the actionEvent class member, or whenever I reference the actionEvent class member.

Comment: When you sum both actions a new one is created but the new action will invoke all the actions that compose it.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're trying to do and all your planteation is wrong. You expect that when you call `actionEvent` outside of this class (from where you pass it as ref) if you have added `callback` to it the `callback` action to be executed. There are too many errors in it to explain: how ref works, what happens when you store a reference, how delegates work and so on. I think what you want to use are `event`s, read how they work as that's what you should be using (and the class `binding` is useless)

Comment: I figured my implementation of the ref keyword was wrong when I kept reading up on it, so I guess it functionally does nothing in this context. So the actionEvent delegate is being cloned whenever I add or remove a callback, but it retains any other methods added? If that’s the case, why isn’t the debug method from the plrInput class being called by the Binding class constructor when I manually invoke it? Also I noticed when I add the same callback to the delegate multiple times, it’s called multiple times on invoke, which is why I created the Binding class.

Comment: Also thank you for the insight, I think I can come up with a solution from here.

Comment: Ok, let me explain why it doesn't works. You have an action A (OnSpacePressed), now you sum A to the callback B(Jump), you will get C that will be C(A,B). When you call A(OnSpacePressed) B(Jump) isn't called as there is no relation, you would need to call C in order to A and B to be called. My first recommendation would be to set `OnSpacePressed` only once in the lifetime of the object that contains it. Else, if it's your object you can check if an event is set testing if it's null, you can create a property on that object thatt checks if the event is set.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Does a delegate assignment create a new copy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155153/does-a-delegate-assignment-create-a-new-copy-in-c) ?

Comment: Yeah, so that along with what Gusman said explains the problem here. Now I have to find out how to get around the delegate being cloned whenever I add or remove the callback. I think I can store a string/delegate array in the plrInput class then reference and change those delegate values from the Binding class with strings, and the plrInput class would invoke the respective array element whenever input occurs instead. There's probably a better solution where I can prevent the delegate from being overwritten before I go and do that though...